# How did this character survive in Knives Out?

Tags: plot-explanation, knives-out

We see Ransom stabbing Marta in the chest, but there was some weird noise, and apparently the kill didn’t work. What did happen? Did the knife retract? I have no clue.

Comment: They demonstrate the retractable feature of the knife immediately after the initial attempt. -1. https://youtu.be/fLkBDy8ZMy0?t=164

Comment: In the movie, it is shown pretty clearly that it is retractable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's a fake knife.

Such knives have a retractable blade, which apparently is not sharp. It is generally harmless and used in party tricks.

[image]

Answer (score 16):

If you recall from earlier in the film, Harlan criticizes Ransom's protected lifestyle saying he is unable to tell the difference between a stage prop and a real knife.  That was a bit of foreshadowing, as Ransom grabs a knife to kill Marta, only to find out she hasn't died.  That's because, as Harlan foreshadowed, Ransom didn't know the difference.